# How to handle exception in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb database. What the MongoDB will return if there any exception while saving,updating or deleting data(or object)?

How to handle exception in MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While making a connection to mongod, set safe to true, for instance here is how it can be done using python driver (pymongo)

```
from pymongo import Connection
connection = Connection('localhost', 27017, safe = True)
```

By doing so you will get write acknowledgements, else it would be simple fire and forget.

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB by default (in some drivers) does not enforce a safe mode whereby the database will physically respond to every call you make to say whether or not it was successful.

However in most drivers there is a `getLastError()` and you can, of course, enforce safe mode on calls using something similar to:

```
update({},{},{safe:true});
```

Using both of these methods will allow you to return problems MongoDB might get in handling your operations.

Comment: Its better to have safe set to true while making Connection itself, instead of passing in every write query.

Comment: Presuming the driver supports that, the PHP driver didn't support that pre-1.3, since we have no idea what driver he is using we cannot make assumptions about that functionality being there